# Text view scrolling with in a limited frame in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

I had a text view above the keyboard like hangout application in iphone. i need to type the character in that as go on it will increses the content scroll with in that frame only.and also the texts needs to be in the correct allignment,I did that in this manner `

```
 -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    {
         NSString *text1 = [textView text];

        CGFloat width = [textView frame].size.width;

        CGSize size = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        textView.contentSize=CGSizeMake([textView frame].size.width, size.height) ;

    }


- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textview
{

    [textView1 resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{

    //delegate=self;
    return YES;
}
```

`But here the problem is it is dancing .not sticking.when ever i am typing the whole area is moving up and down,i need it to be fixed.and when ever i typed and reached the end point it needs to scroll up.Can any body help me in where i am going wrong?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but this is very, very confusing and is quite hard to even comprehend on what is happeneing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For set `contentSize` of `UITextView` no need any code ,  by default it provides this so remove your whole code from `textViewDidChange:` method.

Comment: sorry i dont want to increase the frame .because then it will be ging under my key board ,so i will do it in contentsize height,but the problem is when i try to type its just down ones step then its going up thats the problem

Comment: hey write that code in `shouldChangeTextInRange` method try it out

Comment: @hacker also in `UITextView` not required to set `contentSize` by coding ,here its default to set `contentSize`

Comment: I am not getting uin the second point.the first one is i tried already

Comment: @hacker just remove your whole code from `textViewDidChange:` method nothing add anything also and then test application.. :)

Comment: Thanks it worked.aalso i added textViewShouldEndEditing: to NO

Comment: ur or part is correct so please edit your answer,then i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

> txtView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);

Try this and put dis textview on scrollview.